# Framework Delegates in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks

Hi I created a simple framework with a delegate to return back a value to my main app.

Steps I did:

1. Created a framework in Xcode
2. Created a protocol as public
3. Imported my framework in main app project and integrated my protocol successfully
4. But not able to grab the value from framework

In framework

```
public protocol MyDataSendingDelegateProtocol: NSObject {
func sendDataToFirstViewController(myData: String)
}
public var delegate: MyDataSendingDelegateProtocol? = nil
```

Sending a value form framework as

```
delegate?.sendDataToFirstViewController(myData: "hello world")
```

In the main app

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MyDataSendingDelegateProtocol{

func sendDataToFirstViewController(myData: String) {
    print("from frame work \(myData)")
   }
}
```

Accessing my framework VC

```
public class OOB_View : UIViewController {

public func registraionView() -> UIViewController {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "main", bundle: Bundle(for: oobRegVc.self))
    let homeVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "view") as! oobRegVc
    return homeVC
   }
 }
```

Comment: Add the relevant code.

Comment: @PGDev check my question now

Comment: Where are you setting the delegate as ViewController?

Comment: I don't know where to set that ..help me

Comment: How are you accessing framework's methods? There must be class in which delegate exist right?

Comment: check my question now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217966/discussion-between-mirhpe-danielle-and-pgdev).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **framework** modify the `registraionView` method to accept the `delegate` parameter of type `MyDataSendingDelegateProtocol` and then set it as `homeVC's` `delegate`, i.e.

```
public class OOB_View : UIViewController {
    public func registraionView(delegate: MyDataSendingDelegateProtocol) -> UIViewController {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "main", bundle: Bundle(for: oobRegVc.self))
        let homeVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "view") as! oobRegVc
        homeVC.delegate = delegate
        return homeVC
    }
}
```

Now, in your **main app**, call the method `registraionView(delegate:)` like so,

```
let oobClass = OOB_View()
let x = oobClass.registraionView(delegate: self)
x.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
self.present(x, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The above code must be somewhere in the `ViewController` conforming to `MyDataSendingDelegateProtocol`.